# Regarding the rooms creation in socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I want to create a room in which rooms should be case insensitive means if room  a and room A should open same room or room LOT and room LOt should also same room. So what should i do to make such changes in the room.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit the question to include: the relevant aspects of your existing source code, the output you want, and the output you are getting. That will help the community to help you. At present we really have very little to go on (for example, what is a 'room' in this context?). Thank you.

Comment: Apologies, I see that a room is a component of socket.io. However we still need your source code please.

Answer (score 0):

Convert all characters of your room name to lowercase (or uppercase) before you connect and before you send messages.

Server side:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){

    // Join the room 
    socket.on('join', function(room){
        socket.join(room.toLowerCase());
    }

    // Send message to room
    socket.on('message', function(data){
        socket.broadcast.to(data.room.toLowerCase()).emit('message', data.message);
    }        
});
```

Client side:

```
socket.emit('join', 'RoOmNaMe');
socket.emit('message', { room: 'rOoMnAmE', message: 'Some message...'});
```